# Problem with making a devise scaffolding generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to build a scaffolding generator for Devise and I am having a problem with getting my tests to pass when I uncomment the line `source_root=File.expand_path("../../templates/controllers", __FILE__)`
In my controller action, I am getting the error:

```
Could not find "confirmations_controller.rb" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are:
/home/jackparsons210/devise/lib/generators/active_record/templates
.system temporary path is world-writable: /tmp
/tmp is world-writable: /tmp
[repeated thrice]
```

However, I cannot set source_root twice is there anyway to overcome this, or will I have to hack my own templates using File commands?

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails/generators/active_record'
require 'generators/devise/orm_helpers'
require "generators/devise/controllers_generator.rb"
module ActiveRecord
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::Base
      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      class_option :primary_key_type, type: :string, desc: "The type for primary key"

      include Devise::Generators::OrmHelpers
      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)
    
    
      def copy_devise_migration
        if (behavior == :invoke && model_exists?) || (behavior == :revoke && migration_exists?(table_name))
          migration_template "migration_existing.rb", "#{migration_path}/add_devise_to_#{table_name}.rb", migration_version: migration_version
        else
          migration_template "migration.rb", "#{migration_path}/devise_create_#{table_name}.rb", migration_version: migration_version
        end
      end

      def generate_model
        invoke "active_record:model", [name], migration: false unless model_exists? && behavior == :invoke
      end

      def inject_devise_content
        content = model_contents

        class_path = if namespaced?
          class_name.to_s.split("::")
        else
          [class_name]
        end

        indent_depth = class_path.size - 1
        content = content.split("\n").map { |line| "  " * indent_depth + line } .join("\n") << "\n"

        inject_into_class(model_path, class_path.last, content) if model_exists?
      end

      def migration_data
<<RUBY
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.#{ip_column} :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.#{ip_column} :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at
RUBY
      end

      def ip_column
        # Padded with spaces so it aligns nicely with the rest of the columns.
        "%-8s" % (inet? ? "inet" : "string")
      end

      def inet?
        postgresql?
      end

      def rails5_and_up?
        Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 5
      end

      def rails61_and_up?
        Rails::VERSION::MAJOR > 6 || (Rails::VERSION::MAJOR == 6 && Rails::VERSION::MINOR >= 1)
      end

      def postgresql?
        ar_config && ar_config['adapter'] == 'postgresql'
      end

      def ar_config
        if ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.respond_to?(:configs_for)
          if rails61_and_up?
            ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.configs_for(env_name: Rails.env, name: "primary").configuration_hash
          else
            ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.configs_for(env_name: Rails.env, spec_name: "primary").config
          end
        else
          ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
        end
      end

     def migration_version
       if rails5_and_up?
         "[#{Rails::VERSION::MAJOR}.#{Rails::VERSION::MINOR}]"
       end
     end

     def primary_key_type
       primary_key_string if rails5_and_up?
     end

     def primary_key_string
       key_string = options[:primary_key_type]
       ", id: :#{key_string}" if key_string
     end
    
    
        
            CONTROLLERS = %w(confirmations passwords registrations sessions unlocks omniauth_callbacks).freeze
            puts File.expand_path("../../templates/controllers", __FILE__)
            def create_controllers
                #@_source_root=File.expand_path("../../templates/controllers", __FILE__)
                
                @scope_prefix = table_name.blank? ? '' : ( table_name.camelize + '::')
                controllers = CONTROLLERS
                controllers.each do |name|
                template "#{name}_controller.rb",
                        "app/controllers/#{table_name}/#{name}_controller.rb"
                end
                
            end
            
    end
    

  end
end
```

It looks like the source_root is set on an initializer for thor

```
  def initialize(args = [], options = {}, config = {})
      self.behavior = case config[:behavior].to_s
      when "force", "skip"
        _cleanup_options_and_set(options, config[:behavior])
        :invoke
      when "revoke"
        :revoke
      else
        :invoke
      end

      super
      self.destination_root = config[:destination_root]
    end
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish as a final result. If you want to have a custom reusable way to generate styled devise views as an alternative to `rails g devise:views`, you can look at this gem https://github.com/hisea/devise-bootstrap-views and re-write the views according to your preferences

Comment: I am trying to make a scaffold where it will automatically create models, views and controllers with extra parameters like name:string price:integer, and automatically add those tables to the migration also adding them to the permit action of the controller

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy everything into one file. That's very counterproductive.

```rb
bin/rails g generator auth
```

```rb
# lib/generators/auth/auth_generator.rb

class AuthGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  # To override templates use:
  #
  #   lib/templates/devise
  #   lib/templates/devise/controllers
  #
  # For example, to override one of the controller templates, create:
  #
  #   lib/templates/devise/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb
  #
  def setup_devise
    # Whatever you pass as arguments will be shared with invoked generators
    invoke "devise"
    
    # Because command arguments are shared, you have to make sure that
    # each generator receives correct input. Here, the name has to
    # be plural: User -> users
    invoke "devise:controllers", [plural_name]
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/templates/devise/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb

# TODO: make <%= scope %> controller
```

You can pass extra model attributes to devise generator.

```bash
$ bin/rails g auth User bio:text -c confirmations 
...

$ cat app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb
# TODO: make users controller
```

---

Since `devise:controllers` inherits from `Base` generator instead of `NamedBase`, you don't get any helpers. I don't know a way around that, but all you have to do is call `template` a few times:

```rb
class AuthGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  def setup_devise
    invoke "devise"
  end

  include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers
  source_root File.expand_path("templates", __dir__)

  CONTROLLERS = %w[confirmations passwords registrations sessions unlocks omniauth_callbacks].freeze
  class_option :controllers, aliases: "-c", type: :array, desc: "Select specific controllers to generate (#{CONTROLLERS.join(", ")})"

  def create_controllers
    @scope_prefix = "#{controller_class_name}::"
    controllers = options[:controllers] || CONTROLLERS
    controllers.each do |c|
      template "#{c}_controller.rb", "app/controllers/#{plural_name}/#{c}_controller.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

Now you have to have `source_root` which points to your templates in `lib/generators/auth/templates`:

```rb
# lib/generators/auth/templates/confirmations_controller.rb

class <%= @scope_prefix %>ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
end
```

---

You've made a generator, you can use it somewhere else as well:

```bash
$ bin/rails g generator lazy
```

```rb
# lib/generators/lazy/lazy_generator.rb

class LazyGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  def just_set_it_up
    invoke "auth", ["User", "bio:text"], {controllers: ["confirmations"]}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed and intelligent answer.  However, I think the best course of action is just to make new templates and one new generator which does exactly what I need it to do.  Just invoking devise generator or the controller generator will not do it.     Here is my code thus far for the new generator and test for it.   https://github.com/jackparsons93/devise/blob/main/lib/generators/devise/custom_generator.rb     https://github.com/jackparsons93/devise/blob/main/test/generators/custom_generator_test.rb